# Flask login redirect behind Apache reverse proxy with subpath

Tags: python, apache, redirect, flask, reverse-proxy

My server admin is using Apache to provide a public address by reverse proxying my Flask backend server. Now I don't have much knowledge about `ProxyPass` but he's provided me with this address:

```
http://www.example.com/resources/myproject
```

My Flask server is using `@login_required` decorator to redirect the user to login page when the user hits home without any session. This works well in the local network where `192.168.1.10:5000` is redirected to `192.168.1.10:5000/login`.

But when accessing through the above public address, the  user get redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/login
```

instead of

```
http://www.example.com/resources/myproject/login
```

which in turn, gives a 404 error.

I also logged to see if I was receiving any `X-Forwarded-For` headers so that I can use [this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/35/) to fix the problem, but I don't receive any such header from Apache.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be using [ProxyPassReverse](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassreverse)

Also you wouldn't see an X-Forwarded-For header without setting it in Apache.

Comment: I asked the server admin to send the commands that he is using the following commands to establish the reverse proxy:


`ProxyPass /resources/myproject/ http://192.168.1.10:5000/
ProxyPassReverse /resources/myproject/ http://192.168.1.10:5000/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /resources/myproject/ /resources/myproject/`

Edit: tried formatting the commands

Comment: If you are using ProxyPass you should be able to see the [X-Forwarded-For header](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers), so something must be off with that config, I normally use nginx so I'm not as familiar with Apache configs.